# Mac OS X NPAPI plugin does not show up in Chrome's "about:plugins" list

Tags: macos, plugins, google-chrome, npapi

I'm developing an NPAPI plugin for Mac and it works and registers properly in both Firefox and Safari, but not with Chrome.

The Info.plist for the plugin is adequate enough for Firefox and Safari to acknowledge that it exists in their own plugin listings.  Chrome isn't finding it.  Any ideas?

Info.plist from Xcode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>English</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
<string>XXXXXX</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:XXXXXX}</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>BRPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>WebPluginDescription</key>
<string>XXXXXXX</string>
<key>WebPluginMIMETypes</key>
<dict>
    <key>application/x-XXXXXX-plugin</key>
    <dict>
        <key>WebPluginExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string></string>
            </array>
        <key>WebPluginTypeDescription</key>
        <string>XXXXXX</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>WebPluginName</key>
<string>XXXXXXXXXX</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: is that the whole plist file? Because as you have pasted it it isn't valid XML, which could cause the issue. you're missing the closing tags

Comment: @Taxilian, Some of the text didn't go into the code block.  Fixed.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to checking the plist, Mac Chrome runs CFBundlePreflightExecutable to make sure the plugin is loadable, so perhaps that's the step that's failing. How did you build your plugin? If it's a 64-bit-only binary, Mac Chrome isn't currently capable of loading it, whereas on 10.6 Safari and Firefox are.

Comment: Two issues, 1) the project was built with x86_64 as active architecture, changed this to i386.  2) Chrome does not look in the user's ~/Library/Internet Plug-ins/ - I had to copy it over to the system's /Library/Internet Plug-ins/.  Doing both works!  Thank you!

Comment: The second is not true; Chrome absolutely looks in ~/Library/Internet Plug-ins/; I use this feature all the time with FireBreath plugins.

Comment: This answer saved me yesterday, didn't know about the 32-bit limitation in Chrome. Thanks!